# Send Twitter Direct Message using curl

Tags: curl, twitter, message

Is it possible to send a DM message to a follower in twitter using just CURL. I am able to manually DM between the accounts. This my first foray into twitter app development so any help would be much appreciated.

I tried the following command on my system -usernames/passwords are starred out:

```
curl  --insecure --verbose  --user *****:***** 
--data "text=hello_world&screen_name=***"    
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json
```

And received the following reply:

```
* About to connect() to api.twitter.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 199.16.156.231... connected
* Connected to api.twitter.com (199.16.156.231) port 443 (#0)
* libcurl is now using a weak random seed!
* SSLv2, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, O=Twitter, Inc., OU=Twitter Security, CN=api.twitter.com
*        start date: 2014-08-03 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2016-12-31 23:59:59 GMT
*        subjectAltName: api.twitter.com matched
*        issuer: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10, CN=VeriSi
gn Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
*        SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
* Server auth using Basic with user '********'
> POST /1.1/direct_messages/new.json HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic dGF1cGlyaG86c3ltbWV0cnkz
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.5 (IA64-HP-VMS) libcurl/7.19.5 OpenSSL/0.9.7d
> Host: api.twitter.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 32
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< content-length: 62
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< date: Fri, 29 Apr 2016 09:37:05 GMT
< server: tsa_b
< set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A146192262515114070; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 29-Apr-2018 09:37:05 UTC
< strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
< x-connection-hash: dcb0fd08d7bd0a64a0be40c7552ee0de
< x-response-time: 5
< x-tsa-request-body-time: 0
<
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
                                                              * Connection #0 to host api.twitter.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah Its Possible

Below is the cURL command that I just tried and it worked.

```html
 curl --request 'POST' 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json' --data 'screen_name=(TWITTER ID)&text=hello%2C+tworld.+welcome+to+1.1.' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="**********************", oauth_nonce="**********************", oauth_signature="******************", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="****************", oauth_token="****************************", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

Make sure you have an app created at apps.twitter.com, you can put the website as http://example.com.

Then head over to keys and access token tab and generate token access.

Then headover to [This Page](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/direct_messages/new) and scroll down to OAuth Signature Generator, select your app and you will be redirected to a different page. Make sure all OAuth settings are filled with some random token and keys.Head down to the page and generate OAuth Signature and you will be given a cURL code, post It in terminal and voila!

Ensure you edit RequestQuery screen_name=(TWITTER id OF A PERSON WHO FOLLOWS YOU)

Comment: Thanks for that, but it seems the keys generated are one-shot hits that expire after a minute or two. I need something that I could re-use all the time and automate it.

Comment: ill try a new method myself and get back to you

Comment: Try ysing temboo api. Hit me a thumbs upvif you like the answer